# Perform a list comprehension inside of a for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

In short what I need is to get for each element from this set `uniqueFiles = {volcano_021, opencountry_test_017, opencountry_test_017}` get the element of index 1 from each nested array in which the index 0 is equal to the element of uniqueFiles set which will be iterating.

For instance consider the followin list:

```
    arr = [['volcano_021', 'dusthaze-sky', 5, 1, 251, 55], 
           ['volcano_021', 'rocky-mountain', 11, 75, 249, 256],
           ['opencountry_test_017', 'overcast-sky', 5, 5, 252, 119], 
           ['opencountry_test_017', 'yellow-field', 4, 140, 254, 250],
           ['mountain_004', 'blue-sky', 9, 5, 246, 82]]
```

What I was trying to do is through a for loop get the following result for such a loop

```
'volcano_021' => ['dusthaze-sky','rocky-mountain']
'opencountry_test_017'=> ['overcast-sky', 'yellow-field']
'mountain_004' => ['blue-sky']
```

I came up with the following code...However it is not working.

I would like to do that using a list comprehension

```
  for file in uniqueFiles:
    print([n[1] for i,n in enumerate(arr) if n[i] == file])
```

Comment: Why would using a list comprehension be a constraint here? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "it is not working" is not a valid problem statement.

Comment: Ok, @MadPhysicist...
I am getting the following result
`[]
[]
['dusthaze-sky']`

Comment: How do you expect to get *anything* when your set is three undefined variables -- your stored file names are strings with the same visual value.

Comment: How do you expect to get output for `mountain_004`, when that is not in your set of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need enumerate:

```
for file in uniqueFiles:
    print([n[1] for n in arr if n[0] == file])
```

Answer (score -1):

List comprehensions are for expressing mapping/filtering operations to create lists from arbitrary iterables. What you describe here is a canonical *grouping* operation. So use a dict-based grouping idiom:

```
arr = [['volcano_021', 'dusthaze-sky', 5, 1, 251, 55], 
           ['volcano_021', 'rocky-mountain', 11, 75, 249, 256],
           ['opencountry_test_017', 'overcast-sky', 5, 5, 252, 119], 
           ['opencountry_test_017', 'yellow-field', 4, 140, 254, 250],
           ['mountain_004', 'blue-sky', 9, 5, 246, 82]]
uniqueFiles = {'volcano_021', 'opencountry_test_017', 'opencountry_test_017'}

grouper = {}
for first, second, *_ in arr:
    if first in uniqueFiles:
        grouper.setdefault(first, []).append(second)
```

Which would give you a result like:

```
>>> grouper
{'volcano_021': ['dusthaze-sky', 'rocky-mountain'], 'opencountry_test_017': ['overcast-sky', 'yellow-field']}
```

You could use an algorithm like:

```
>>> [[y for x,y,*_ in arr if x == target] for target in uniqueFiles]
[['dusthaze-sky', 'rocky-mountain'], ['overcast-sky', 'yellow-field']]
```

But note, this requires several passes over `arr`, making the above algorithm O(N*M) on the sizes of `arr` and `uniqueList`, which is polynomial time, but the dict-based grouping idiom is linear time, O(N) on the length of `arr`